# Group Months in string type to quarters in string type and add values on pandas df column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to sum the values of every quarter, and rename it to 2000q1 format. This is returning a value, but I am not sure if it is the right one. To test it I am running a sum between the original columns and checking the values. What do you think about the method below?

```
        homes = homes[['State', 'RegionName', '2000-01', '2000-02', '2000-03', '2000-04', '2000-05', "2000-06", "2000-07", "2000-08", "2000-09", "2000-10", "2000-11", "2000-12", "2001-01", "2001-02", "2001-03","2001-04","2001-05","2001-06","2001-07","2001-08","2001-09","2001-10","2001-11","2001-12","2002-01","2002-02","2002-03","2002-04","2002-05","2002-06","2002-07","2002-08","2002-09","2002-10","2002-11","2002-12","2003-01","2003-02","2003-03","2003-04","2003-05","2003-06","2003-07","2003-08","2003-09","2003-10","2003-11","2003-12","2004-01","2004-02","2004-03","2004-04","2004-05","2004-06","2004-07","2004-08","2004-09","2004-10","2004-11","2004-12","2005-01","2005-02","2005-03","2005-04","2005-05","2005-06","2005-07","2005-08","2005-09","2005-10","2005-11","2005-12","2006-01","2006-02","2006-03","2006-04","2006-05","2006-06","2006-07","2006-08","2006-09","2006-10","2006-11","2006-12","2007-01","2007-02","2007-03","2007-04","2007-05","2007-06","2007-07","2007-08","2007-09","2007-10","2007-11","2007-12","2008-01","2008-02","2008-03","2008-04","2008-05","2008-06","2008-07","2008-08","2008-09","2008-10","2008-11","2008-12","2009-01","2009-02","2009-03","2009-04","2009-05","2009-06","2009-07","2009-08","2009-09","2009-10","2009-11","2009-12","2010-01","2010-02","2010-03","2010-04","2010-05","2010-06","2010-07","2010-08","2010-09","2010-10","2010-11","2010-12","2011-01","2011-02","2011-03","2011-04","2011-05","2011-06","2011-07","2011-08","2011-09","2011-10","2011-11","2011-12","2012-01","2012-02","2012-03","2012-04","2012-05","2012-06","2012-07","2012-08","2012-09","2012-10","2012-11","2012-12","2013-01","2013-02","2013-03","2013-04","2013-05","2013-06","2013-07","2013-08","2013-09","2013-10","2013-11","2013-12","2014-01","2014-02","2014-03","2014-04","2014-05","2014-06","2014-07","2014-08","2014-09","2014-10","2014-11","2014-12","2015-01","2015-02","2015-03","2015-04","2015-05","2015-06","2015-07","2015-08","2015-09","2015-10","2015-11","2015-12","2016-01","2016-02","2016-03","2016-04","2016-05","2016-06","2016-07","2016-08"]]
        years = homes.iloc[:, 3:]
        years = years.groupby(pd.to_datetime(years.columns).to_period('Q'), axis=1).sum() # GROUP ALL MONTHS TO QUARTERS and sum their values !
        years.columns = years.columns.strftime('%Y'+'q'+'%q')

        #print years
        homes = homes[['State', 'RegionName']]
        homes = pd.merge(homes, years, how='outer', left_index=True, right_index=True)
        homes['State'] = homes['State'].apply(state_names_transformed)
        #homes.columns = homes.columns.str.replace('Q', 'q')
        homes = homes.set_index(['State', 'RegionName'])
        return homes
```